# Use binding file to set the package on a namespace?

Tags: jaxb, moxy

I'm working on two large 3rd party schemas, one includes the other and generates a large number of type name collisions. If I could set the package on a namespace this problem would go away.

I hoped something like

```
<jaxb:bindings namespace="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9" >
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="org.oagis" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

would work, or perhaps

```
<jaxb:bindings node="/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9']">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="org.oagis" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But no joy.

Trying to set on the individual xsd files in that namespace left me with the dread

```
[ERROR] Multiple <schemaBindings> are defined for the target namespace "http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9"
```

Pointers/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hard to answer without seeing the whole compilation. However I often got this error when compiling third-party schemas in the case when the same schema was included via different URLs.

I.e. I've implemented a [project](https://java.net/projects/OGC) which compiled an extensive set of [OGC Schemas](http://schemas.opengis.net/). The problem was that these schemas referenced each other via relative and absolute URLs. So when I customized one of the schemas there were *other* schemas for the same namespace URI. Since JAXB processes imports and includes, it is not quite transparent what exactly gets compiled. Try to check your XJC logs for cues or - if you compile schemas directly via URLs (which is not recommended) - go through a logging proxy and see what actually gets accessed.

Comment: Ah, I suspect this is the case. There are "common" schemas that are both included and imported multiple times. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Looks like there are a number of issues related to namespaces, import vs include, and recognizing duplicates based on URI. I'm going to have to go in and rationalize/normalize paths and that should clear it up. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Another hint: the best way to approach this is with catalog files. You can basically "replace" URLs with other URLs. My recommendation is to have a complete local copy of schemas you want to compile and configure catalog files for all of the included/imported URLs. Unfortunatelly it is not trivial. I did it a few times, is no fun job.

Comment: I was just going down the catalog path :-)  Thanks for the validation.